# problemas con los nodos de mi cluster

Tags: cluster

Mi aplicación trata de crear un **PDF** (entre otras cosas) y esta alojada en un servidor que tiene 2 nodos de `Cluster` pero eso hace que el **PDF** se genere 2 veces. el problema esta en la configuración del `Cluster` o yo debo de solucionarlo con programación, muchas gracias

Comment: Es el comportamiento esperado, cada nodo tiene su entorno. Una posible solución es montar un sistema de archivos compartido (local o distribuido según como sea el cluster) y que cada nodo/proceso verifique que el archivo no existe antes de crearlo.